# How to have two separate functions not interfere with another?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I have an alert message that appears on the page for the first time creating a cookie on Dismiss. I created a function on page load to check if the cookie exists, do not display alert and if it does not exist display alert message. I also have another function in place to check if the `pageTitle` is "Test" display the alert message.

At the moment my alert message is showing even after clicking dismiss and a cookie is generated because of the second function check on pageTitle. If I remove the check on pageTitle I do get the desired result I want but the message appears on all pages when I only want it to appear with the `pageTitle = Test`

I am attempting to have both checks work properly with one another for example, `if cookie exists do not show an alert, if it doesn't exist and the pageTitle = test show alert message`

First function

```
  $(window).on("load", function (e) {
    $('.preloader').fadeOut('slow');

    if (document.cookie.includes("isDismissed=true")) {

        document.body.classList.add("alert.container");
    } else {
        document.body.classList.add("show-alert");
    }
});
```

Second function

```
 if("@pageTitle".indexOf("Test")  !== -1) {
       document.body.classList.add("show-alert");
    }
```

Comment: I don't see second function, I only see another if condition, from where it is called ?

Comment: I am new to web development so I apologize if my terminology is not correct but I am referring to the second if statement as my "second function" I simply have the if statement check in my <script> tags

Comment: remove the alert-container from the class list in the else part and use jQuery for adding removing classes and remove the show-alert from the classlist in the if block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the second code as an `else if` in the first function.

```
$(window).on("load", function(e) {
  $('.preloader').fadeOut('slow');

  if (document.cookie.includes("isDismissed=true")) {
    document.body.classList.add("alert.container");
  } else if ("@pageTitle".indexOf("Test") !== -1) {
    document.body.classList.add("show-alert");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:
Check if the cookie exists in the second function.

```
if("@pageTitle".indexOf("Test")  !== -1 && !document.cookie.includes("isDismissed=true")) {
   document.body.classList.add("show-alert");
}
```

Check if if the page title includes test on the first function.

```
$(window).on("load", function (e) {
  $('.preloader').fadeOut('slow');

  if (document.cookie.includes("isDismissed=true")) {
    document.body.classList.add("alert.container");
  } else if ("@pageTitle".indexOf("Test")  !== -1) {
    document.body.classList.add("show-alert");
  }
});
```

If both of these functions are ran on load, this is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to remove the class from the class list, it will keep on adding

```
$(window).on("load", function (e) {
    $('.preloader').fadeOut('slow');

    if (document.cookie.includes("isDismissed=true")) {
        $("body").removeClass("show-alert").addClass("alert.container");
    } else {
        $("body").removeClass("alert.container").addClass("show-alert");
    }
});
```